# How to prevent the labels & textboxes from increasing and size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I have a page ([codepen](https://codepen.io/RobertGelb/pen/QmKvry)) which utilizes both bootstrap & flexbox (i have good reasons for that):

```
  body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
  }
```

When the user clicks the YES radio box, a bit of JavaScript shows another label with YES/NO question.  When that happens is that the `Email Address` textbox at the top expands even through though nothing has changed for it.  This is caused by flexbox, I suspect.  The `Are you a fantastic human being` is also reflowed.

Is there a way to stop both the label and the textbox from changing size?

P.S.  If anyone is wondering why I didn't use SO's snippet utility, the problem only appears when the Results page is full width of the browser and Codepen lets you do that.

Comment: `max-width: ` ...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to give `.app-content` a max-width so to prevent the textboxes to increase size. e.g.

```
.app-content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to measure out the initial width of the form (which is 275px) and set the "max-width" of the container to this value.

```
.app-content {
  max-width: 275px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```